# I am not able to change the app icon for Expo IOS build

Tags: react-native, expo

I have built an app on Expo Go and tried everything to change the default logo of the app and it's showing the new logo in the android build and even the simulator build for ios but the it shows the default logo when I build my .ipa file for IOS.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

In your app.json go to this key and change the path of the icon. Make sure you dont include the path of the icon in the android object or ios

```html
  "expo": {
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "icon": "./app/assets/icon.png",
    }
```